# one to many or many to many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-core

I am trying to make a Leave Management System and trying to figure out the relationship between the Leave and Employee class/table. Would it be one to many (single employee can take many leaves) or would it be many to many (single employee can take many leaves and Leave is taken by many employees)? Am I approaching it the right way? According to me it is many to many.
Sorry if the questions is not properly framed. Still very new to learning it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One instance of leave corresponds only to one employee. If there were multiple instances of employees taking leave on the same date period, they would still be attached to the individual employees. Employees do not 'share' leave, so therefore I think it's actually one-to-many.